# How to remove redirection

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

I have two sites in a local environment over Nginx server.

superbiajuridico.test (site 1)

quercusjuridico.test (site 2)

These sites are very similar (same theme and similar content). WordPress showed me a dialog box saying that "this site seems to be a copy of another", and a button to confirm. I confirmed it (bad idea). After that, one of the sites is unreachable because a redirection.

When I go to

```
http://superbiajuridico.test/wp/wp-admin
```

I'm redirected this way:

```
http://quercusjuridico.test/wp/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fsuperbiajuridico.test%2Fwp%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

How can I remove this redirection? Where is it stored?

Nginx blocks and etc/hosts are clean. My guess is that, in some point, WordPress wrote a PHP redirection. Is it possible?

Comment: This is not stored somewhere on the server. Check the DB of `superbiajuridico` to make sure the URL is correct in `wp_options` and everywhere else. I don't think "this site seems to be a copy of another" is a WordPress core feature, so if fixing DB doesn't solve it, I would try to find out where this dialog was coming from.

Comment: Ok. Maybe a WPML dialog box? Checking DB.